# Convert Pytorch model into Tensorflow: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, onnx, yolov5

I am converting pytorch model into Tensorflow. For that Pytorch-ONNX-Tensorflow this are the steps I am following, but while exporting Pytorch model into ONNX getting the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Below is the code snippet:

```
trained_model = Net()
trained_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('best.pt'))
dummy_input = Variable(torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28))
torch.onnx.export(trained_model, dummy_input, "best.onnx")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste the rest of the code. Because the error probably coming from another part of the code.

Comment: Also post the full error traceback

Comment: model_path = '/content/yolov5s.pt' 
# Load the weights 
state_dict = torch.load(model_path)

Comment: @DerekG :         
      
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in find_class(self, mod_name, name)
    873         def find_class(self, mod_name, name):
    874             mod_name = load_module_mapping.get(mod_name, mod_name)
    875             return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
    876 
    877     # Load the data (which may in turn use `persistent_load` to load tensors)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'